# How to exchange data between different processes using MPI

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, mpi, openmp

I'm trying to use `MPI_Sendrecv` to exchange data between processes but get trapped in the send and receive logics.

Assume that we have four processes, and each of them has 2 1D arrays of size 4: `Params` and `Params_`. The entries of `Params` will be initialized to be `rank * 4 + i` (e.g. in process rank 0, `Params = {0,1,2,3}`), while `Params_` is used to store the `Params` sent by the other processes. Every process is going to send its `params` to the others and receive the `params` from the others. The code is as follows.

```
#include<mpi.h>
#include<stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv){
  int my_rank, ncpus;
  MPI_Status status;

  MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
  MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &my_rank);
  MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &ncpus);

  double *params;
  double *params_;
  int Nparams = 4;

  params = new double[Nparams];
  params_ = new double[Nparams];

  // Initialize params and print it
  printf("ID %d: ", my_rank);
  for (int i = 0; i < Nparams; i++) {
    params[i] = my_rank * ncpus + i;
    printf("%g  ", params[i]);
  }
  printf("\n");

  // Receive params from the other processes, store it in params_, and print it
  for (int i = 0; i < ncpus; i++) {
    MPI_Sendrecv(params, Nparams, MPI_DOUBLE, i, 0, params_, Nparams, MPI_DOUBLE, i, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
    printf("Receive params from %d: ", i);
    for (int i = 0; i < Nparams; i++)
      printf("%g  ", params_[i]);
    printf("\n");
  }

  delete[] params;
  delete[] params_;
  MPI_Finalize();
  return 0;
}
```

The output of the code shows nothing (even cannot print out `Params`), and there are a lot of warnings like `WARNING: There was an error initializing an OpenFabrics device`. Could you help me figure out why this doesn't work and what I should do. Thanks a lot!

Comment: _Every process is going to send its params to the others and receive the params from the others._ For this operation, you should use `MPI_Allgather`, not `MPI_Sednrecv`.

Comment: The code runs/prints for me, maybe be a problem with your MPI installation. Is it intel MPI using OpenFabrics? might be worth including this tag and some more details (and removing OpenMP)

Comment: @EdSmith Oh really, I'm using a cluster and loaded `openmpi_4.0.0_gcc`, compile it with `mpicxx main.cpp -o main`, and run `srun --mpi=pmi2 ./main`. Can you post the result? Thanks a lot!

Comment: @DanielLangr `MPI_Allgather` is a feasible way, but it seems that more memories are required. That is, the size of `params_` would be four times that of `params` (having 4 processes totally). How can I make `params_` has the same size with `params`?

Comment: @GENGYANG You're right, `MPI_Allgather` requires more space. But it will be likely much faster at large scales. It then depends on priorities what do you prefer.